# Loading HTML Table from Nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js

From a nodejs app I want to load a web page from a url. I know that has a single html table. How do I iterate each row and column to traverse every value in that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need some middleware, [request](https://github.com/request/request) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) could be used for this

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://www.example.com/url/tofile.html', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

     var $     = cheerio.load(body);
     var table = $('table#withID');
     var tr    = table.find('tr');
     var res   = [];

     tr.each(function() {
         var txt = $(this).find('td').text();

         res.push(txt);
     });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2

Then catch onopentag for "td".